# In 5th ed would a bard who multi-class as a life domain cleric have his bard healing spells improved?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, cleric, bard

I have a 9th level bard. Hypothetically, if when I reached 10th level I took a level in cleric and chose the life domain, so I would be bard 9/cleric 1.

The multi-classing rules state "When you gain a new level in a class, you get its features for that level" and then lists a bunch of exceptions, none of which apply to this situation.

In the cleric class, at level 1 you take a domain. The life domain has an ability called disciple of life which reads

> Also starting at first level, your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level."

Note that it says healing spells, not specifically cleric ones.

It would seem the RAW here is that this would apply to my bard spells as well. So my mass cure wounds (which is 5th level and I would not be able to know as a cleric spell but which I do know as a bard spell), would heal everything an additional 7 points.

Is this how multiclassing works? It seems like my best multi-class option if it does (although I'd probably wait until 11th level since level 10 bards get awesome stuff). Am I missing something?

Comment: I've marked your question as a duplicate because I feel the other question effectively covers this one. If you feel it does not ask the same thing or that there is something specific to these features that makes it unclear, feel free to say so or explain why in an edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This works.

[Disciple of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain) reads:

> Whenever you use a *spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature*, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

The only eligibility condition for  this ability to apply is that you "use a spell of 1st level or higher that restores hit points to a creature". So your Bard spells will qualify.

To contrast, here is an example of a Cleric ability that modifies *only* cleric spells, the [Death Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DeathDomain)'s Inescapable Destruction:

> Starting at 6th level, the cleric’s ability to channel negative energy becomes more potent. Necrotic damage dealt by the **character’s cleric spells** and Channel Divinity options ignores resistance to necrotic damage.

Here we see that when the rules intend for an ability to work only on a particular class's spells, they specify particularly which class's spells.